# I want to make an html select tag dropdown searchable. I am open to use MUI component instead of it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I want the first value to be default selected and set, which i am currently handling. So, i dont want to change the working... just want to add a search feature in the dropdown. I can use something like Autocomplete from MUI.

````
<div className="flex flex-col">
                <label className="text-[14px] pl-1">Symbol</label>
                <select
                  className="border text-sm p-1 pr-4 w-[180px] border-gray-500 rounded-md bg-[#081D26] hover:border-gray-100 focus:outline-none cursor-pointer"
                  value={selectedUnderlying}
                  onChange={(e) => setSelectedUnderlying(e.target.value)}
                >
                  {multilegData?.Underlyings.map((option, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={option}>
                      {option}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </div>
    ```
````